# Cant call socket.io's io from main nodejs server

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sockets, socket.io

I got a `server.js` and and `socket.js` file. when i try to call `io` from socket.js file, it says i have to initialize server first. The point i already did that. Am i missing  a point?

File: `server.js`

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const userRouter = require("./api/users/user.router");
// CATCH THE ERROR
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  const message = error.message;
  const data = error.data;
  res.json({ message: message, data: data, result: false });
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/customers", userRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const serverInstance = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("app running at http://localhost:" + port);
});

// INITIALIZE SOCKET.IO
require("./socket").initIO(serverInstance);
require("./api/users/user.router")(app);
```

File: `socket.js`

```
let io;

const initIO = (server) => {
  // start socket.io server and cache io value
  io = require("socket.io")(server);
  return io;
};

const getIO = () => {
  // return previously cached value
  if (!io) {
    throw new Error("must call .initIO(server) before you can call .getIO()");
  }
  return io;
};

module.exports = {
  initIO,
  getIO,
};
```